# How to Special Characters in xml under SQL Server 2012 FileTable

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have sample XML file in a SQL Server 2012 `FileTable`.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Company>
         <Comp id="c101">
               <Name>Tony Jaw</Name>  
               <SplChar>$</SplChar>   
               <Place>US</Place>
         </Comp>
</Company>
```

Problem: we can search 'Tony' or 'Jaw' in `FileTable` by executing the below query. We will get the result.

```
Select * 
From FileTable 
where FREETEXT(file_stream,'Tony')
```

But, I am not able search special characters ($) in xml file by executing the below query

```
Select * 
From FileTable 
where FREETEXT(file_stream,'$')
```

Please explain anyone.........

Actually FILE_STREAM column contains the actual data in SQL Server `FileTable`. So I am searching for special characters(! or @ or # or $ or % or ^ ) in File_Stream column

Modified query :

```
Select * 
From FileTable 
where CONTAINS(file_stream,'"$"')
```

Output: No result

Answer (score 1):

You have to delimit special characters

```
where file_stream CONTAINS(ColName,'"$"')
```

See FTS team blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlfts/archive/2009/12/09/gotchas-on-searching-for-at-t-m-m-etc.aspx

Comment: Actually FILE_STREAM column contains the actual data in Sql Server File Table. So i am searching for special characters(! or @ or # or $ or % or ^ ) in File_Stream column. My query is

Select * From FileTable where CONTAINS(file_stream,'$')

Output : No Result

Comment: @user2306192: did you add double quotes as per my example? That is, `CONTAINS(file_stream,'"$"')`